# How to open SAP Transaction from Fiori App

Tags: sapui5

Hi i want to open a transactionof my back-end, i used this code but only open the transaction of my fiori server:

```
var sURI = "http://vm-kfmfiori.grupokaufmann.com:8000/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui?~transaction=/DBM/ORDER03";
            window.open(sURI);
```

But i want to open it from my back-end and if it possible to open it inside the app not another tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do this!

However, here is the way how you can do this:

1. Expose GUI transaction as a Fiori app : [How to open SAP GUI transaction in Fiori Launchpad](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/21/open-your-sap-gui-transaction-in-fiori-launchpad/)
2. Navigate to this application from your Fiori application : [How to perform cross-app navigation between Fiori Application](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/20/cross-application-navigation-between-sapui5-applications/)

Let me know if this helps.